# How to use SqlDataReader to get a value from a select without knowing its position on Visual Studio

Tags: c#, vb.net, vb.net-to-c#

I've translating a few things from VB to C# but there is something I haven't figured out how to do...

This is the entire function

```vb
Function get_projects_by_user(Optional uid As String = "", Optional filter As String = "%") As String()
    Dim returnArray(1) As String
    Dim count As Integer = 1
    Dim SQLConn As New SqlConnection() 'The SQL Connection
    Dim SQLCmd As New SqlCommand() 'The SQL Command
    Dim SQLdr As SqlDataReader 'The Local Data Store

    returnArray(1) = ""

    SQLConn.ConnectionString = ConStr  'Set the Connection String
    SQLConn.Open() 'Open the connection
    SQLCmd.Connection = SQLConn 'Sets the Connection to use with the SQL Command

    SQLCmd.CommandText = Replace(Replace(ASK_PROJECTS_BY_USERS, "PAR1", uid), "PAR2", filter) 'Sets the SQL String
    SQLdr = SQLCmd.ExecuteReader 'Gets Data

    While SQLdr.Read()
        count = count + 1
        ReDim Preserve returnArray(count)
        returnArray(count) = SQLdr("codigo") & " - " & SQLdr("nomeProjeto")
    End While

    SQLdr.Close() 'Close the SQLDataReader
    SQLConn.Close() 'Close the connection

    Return returnArray
End Function
```

The part I'm having problems with is this:

```vb
returnArray(count) = SQLdr("codigo") & " - " & SQLdr("nomeProjeto")
```

I don't know how to do this in C# (get the values from the name and not position).

Comment: c# uses brackets: `SQLdr["codigo"].ToString()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VB.NET uses parenthesis to access the [default property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az06zx4y%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) of an object, whereas C# uses square brackets to access the [indexer property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx) (indexers are essentially the C# equivalent of VB's default properties).  So, where in VB.NET you would use `SQLdr("codigo")` to access the value of the column by name, in C# the equivalent would be `SQLdr["codigo"]`.  The same syntactical difference exists for accessing items in arrays.

In this case, the indexer/default property for the `SqlDataReader` class is the [`Item`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az06zx4y%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) property.  That means that in that in VB.NET, you can access the property using either the default property syntax or the `Item` property explicitly:

```vb
'Using the default property syntax
Dim value As Object = SQLdr("codigo")

'Using the Item property explicitly
Dim value As Object = SQLdr.Item("codigo")
```

In C#, the `Item` property is hidden and is only accessible via the indexer syntax.

As a side-note, you can also use the `GetOrdinal` method to get the index of a column given its name.  For instance:

```cs
int index = SQLdr.GetOrdinal("codigo");
```

or in VB.NET

```vb
Dim index As Integer = SQLdr.GetOrdinal("codigo")
```

Comment: I thought for a minute Mark Zuckerberg answered this!

Comment: @JonH, surely you mean that for a moment you thought that it was actually Steven Doggart that had started Facebook!

Answer (score 0):

A few usages in your while(SQLdr.Read()):

```
int:       int.Parse(reader["Id"].ToString()),
timestamp: (byte[])(reader["TimeStampOperation"]),
DateTime:  DateTime.Parse(reader["DateTime"].ToString()),
string:    reader["FirstName"].ToString();
```

The ["string"] between the reader-brackets (like Id, FirstName, ...) is a table-field of a SQL-table

Hope to be of help...